# multiple if condition throws error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using below if condition in shell script

```
   if [! -z "$failedTC"] || [-n "$failedTC"];
   then
   echo "ITS not empaty AND NOT NULL"
   else
   echo "ITS empty or NULL"
   fi
```

The above code I'm checking the $failedTC shouldn't be null and empty. But the if condition throws below error message in jenkins. I used the above script in jenkins Execute Shell window.

> /tmp/jenkins371454092166709762.sh: line 23: [!: command not found
>   /tmp/jenkins371454092166709762.sh: line 23: [-n: command not found

Any leads....

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a space after the opening brackets and before the closing brackets in your conditionals:

Change

```
if [! -z "$failedTC"] || [-n "$failedTC"];
```

to

```
if [ ! -z "$failedTC" ] || [ -n "$failedTC" ];
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that, it needs a `space` before and after every square bracket`[]`.

Try this:

```
if [ ! -z "$failedTC" ] || [ -n "$failedTC" ];
   then
   echo "ITS not empaty AND NOT NULL"
   else
   echo "ITS empty or NULL"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

"[" and "]" are commands, it should be wrapped around spaces " [ ". that is the best practice. try this

```
  if [ ! -z "$failedTC" ] || [ -n "$failedTC" ];
   then
   echo "ITS not empaty AND NOT NULL"
   else
   echo "ITS empty or NULL"
   fi
```